# PageMethods not working

Tags: javascript, vb.net, pagemethods

I am trying to learn how to use PageMethods with VB.NET and I'm running into some issues. For some reason I can't manage to get the method called by PageMethods to run.

Here is the javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AddHouse() {
        var address = document.getElementById("addrTxt").valueOf;
        var city = document.getElementById("cityTxt").valueOf;
        var state = document.getElementById("stateTxt").valueOf;
        var zip = parseInt(document.getElementById("zipTxt").valueOf);
        var firstName = document.getElementById("rFirstName").valueOf;
        var lastName = document.getElementById("rLastName").valueOf;
        var rent = parseInt(document.getElementById("rentAmt").valueOf);
        PageMethods.InsertHouse(address, city, state, zip, firstName, lastName, rent);
    }
</script>
```

And here's the VB.NET code:

```
Public Class _Default
Inherits Page

Private Shared dbConnection As String
Private file As String = "C:\\Projects\\HousingInfo\\HousingInfo\\bin\\housingInfo.db3"

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    dbConnection = String.Format("Data Source={0}", file)
    CreateTables()
End Sub

Private Sub CreateTables()
    Dim connection = New SQLiteConnection(dbConnection)
    If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\\Projects\\HousingInfo\\HousingInfo\\bin\\housingInfo.db3") Then
        SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("C:\\Projects\\HousingInfo\\HousingInfo\\bin\\housingInfo.db3")
    End If
    Using Query As New SQLiteCommand()
        connection.ConnectionString = dbConnection
        connection.Open()
        With Query
            .Connection = connection
            .CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS houses(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, address TEXT, city TEXT, state TEXT,
                zipCode INTEGER, rent INTEGER, rFirstName TEXT, rLastName TEXT)"
        End With
        Query.ExecuteNonQuery()
        connection.Close()
    End Using
End Sub

<Services.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Sub InsertHouse(ByVal addr As String, ByVal city As String, ByVal state As String, ByVal zip As Integer, ByVal firstName As String,
                              ByVal lastName As String, ByVal rent As Integer)
    Dim connection = New SQLiteConnection(dbConnection)
    Using Query As New SQLiteCommand()
        connection.ConnectionString = dbConnection
        connection.Open()
        With Query
            .Connection = connection
            .CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO houses(address, city, state, zipCode, rent, rFirstName, rLastName) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', {3}, {4}, '{5}', '{6}'",
                                         addr, city, state, zip, firstName, lastName, rent)
        End With
        Query.ExecuteNonQuery()
        connection.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting to PageMethods.InsertHouse line? What JS error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong property to get the value of the controls, rename 'valueOf' to 'value' as follows:

Do this for all other occurrences of 'valueOf'

```
var address = document.getElementById("addrTxt").value;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it still is not calling the method.